# changing column types of a pandas data frame -- finding offending rows that prevent casting

Tags: python, pandas

My PANDAS data has columns that were read as objects. I want to change these into floats. Following the post linked below ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/pandas-change-data-type-of-columns)), I tried:

```
pdos[cols] = pdos[cols].astype(float)
```

But PANDAS gives me an error saying that an object can't be recast as float.

> ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 17_d

But when I search for 17_d in my data set, it tells me it's not there.

```
>>> '17_d' in pdos
 False
```

I can look at the raw data to see what's happening outside of python, but feel if I'm going to take python seriously, I should know how to deal with this sort of issue. Why doesn't this search work? How could I do a search over objects for strings in PANDAS? Any advice?

[Pandas: change data type of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/pandas-change-data-type-of-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

of course it does, because you're only looking in the column list!

```
'17_d' in pdos
```

checks to see if `'17_d'` is in `pdos.columns`

so what you want to do is `pdos[cols] == '17_d'`, which will give you a truth table. if you want to find which row it is, you can do `(pdos[cols] == '17_d').any(1)`